# How to ask Dev-Containers plugin of VSCode to use `sudo docker`?

Tags: docker, vscode-remote, vscode-devcontainer

I tried to use the Dev-Containers form VSCode to connect to my containers in a remote Linux Server. For security reason we cannot create a `docker` user group since the docker group grants root-level privileges to the user, but I can run the `docker` command with `sudo`.

Is there a way to tell Dev-Containers to use sudo for docker commands? Otherwise it gives me the error: "Current user does not have permission to run 'docker'." when trying to attach an existing container.

I tried to search the issues and questions on github and stackoverflow but did not successfully find a solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `dev.containers.dockerPath` setting to specify an alternate executable to use for the `docker` binary.

But since you can only specify an executable and not a commandline with it you would need to write a small wrapper script like

```bash
#!/bin/sh

sudo docker "$@"
```

and then use it with:

```json
{
   // ...
   "dev.containers.dockerPath": "/path/to/sudo-docker.sh"
}
```

Comment: Thank you! This is working! I think one of my problems is I didn't find the docker path in settings because I was using an old version of Remote - SSH, I updated it to v0.106 and set the docker path as you said and it's working fine now.